# Is it possible to make a donation button in my website with choices? Whether Paypal or Credit Card?

Tags: php, paypal

I already created a donation button and tested it in sandbox and it worked, what I want to do is before the donor clicks the donate button, I want them to choose first whether Credit Card or PayPal Account, if they choose credit card, they will fill the form and redirect to PayPal. I don't want them to choose credit card at PayPal site because it is so small that it can barely seen.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to open up the credit card field on the paypal checkout page using website Payments Standard buttons(like donations,buy now etc)But,you can [automatically fill](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_prepopulate_outside) the address related fields and pass it to checkout page.

You can display the credit card tab only in [express checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) using LANDINGPAGE=Billing

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an idea.

**Your Question:**
If they choose credit card, they will fill the form and redirect to PayPal.

**Answer:**
This can be done, however you will invoke SOLUTIONTYPE=SOLE and LANDINGPAGE=BILLING (this will work using PayPal buttons; I have tested this first hand)

**Answer:**
Technically it could be done, however it is an unsecured method of using a customers credit and sort of defeats the purpose of using PayPal as a payment method; invalidates security. If you post credit card data from your; let's say secure form, it is still vulnerable to a post sniff where hackers can steal the cc info vs. having the customer manually entering their credit card info on a hosted secure paypal page.

**Note**
Maybe use PayPal advanced which is $5 a month; use a secure hosted Iframe, where a customer can pay with a credit card on site with no redirect. Like: http://www.ggsalsa.com/salsa-menu.html#!/~/checkoutPD; put fake email and checkout with credit card to see.